# Managing multiple UICollectionViewLayouts within a single UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, ios7, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, cocoa-design-patterns

Apologies if this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find anything on an initial search. And I'm struggling to get my head around the design.

I am attempting to create some interactive transitions between UICollectionViewLayouts using the new iOS7 APIs - [UICollectionViewTransitionLayout Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewTransitionLayout_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UICollectionViewTransitionLayout)

However, I am unsure how best to manage multiple `UICollectionViewLayouts` within a single `UICollectionViewController`, or how to interactively move between one and another `UICollectionViewController`.

This question is more of a design issue, on how to write the code rather than not understanding the actual implementation of interactive layouts and changing layouts - should I be using a `UICollectionViewController`? I don't really need to subclass a `UICollectionViewLayout` as I am quite happy with the functionality the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` provides.

My ideal and final goal is achieve a `UIViewController` (or multiple `UIViewControllers`) that each have a UICollectionView within them, that get push and popped between using `UIGestureRecognizers`.

Thanks.

EDIT

Also found a similar question that was submitted just before mine, [UICollectionView interactive layout transition using iOS 7 APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19008307/uicollectionview-interactive-layout-transition-using-ios-7-apis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I have uploaded my code for my solution to GitHub... it is a work in progress

[UICollectionView Interactive Transitions](https://github.com/timsearle/UICollectionView-Interactions)

I have decided on a solution where I will use a single `UIViewController`, that will maintain several `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` objects, defined as properties on the controller.

Each will be configured according to how I wish the UICollectionView to look.

I will then make use of interactive transitioning with iOS7 to handle transitioning between the two defined layouts. I can also use this basic call to handle quick non-interactive transitions:

```
[UICollectionView setCollectionView:animated:]
```

I didn't receive an answer, so unfortunately do not know if this is the best way to approach the problem.